# how can i capture image gallery's without a range

Tags: preg-match-all

i have already this code

but for this it makes a pattern like image[1-10].jpg
but what i want is to fetch the gallley like this above but also like domain.com/gallery/
what do i get to chance to get this working.

hope someone can tel me the tric.

```
$parts = preg_split("/\[\d+-\d+\]/", $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
preg_match_all("/\[\d+-\d+\]/", $url, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$parts_number = count($parts);
$matches_number = count($matches[0]);
// JYM
if ($parts_number==1) {

    $image_alt_url=$url;
    $url = str_replace("[", '', $url);
    $url = str_replace("]", '', $url);

    $alto = str_replace("/", '_', $image_alt_url);
    $alto = str_replace("www", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("http", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("https", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("jpg", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("com", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("net", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("info", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace(".com.np", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("org", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace(".", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace(":_", '', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("-", '_', $alto);
    $alto = preg_replace("/[^a-z-_]/",'',$alto);
    $alto = str_replace("__", '_', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("___", '_', $alto);
    $alto = str_replace("_", '-', $alto);
    $alto=substr($alto, 1, -1);



    $ary_header = get_headers($url, 1);
    $filesize = $ary_header['Content-Length'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't provide any sample inputs, and no expected result, I am forced to make several assumptions:

```
$url="https://www.example.com/gallery/image3.jpg, example.com/gallery/image9.jpg, http://example.com/gallery/image14.JPG";
if(!preg_match_all("/([^, ]*\/)([^,]*?(\d+).jpg)/i",$url,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    echo "No Matches Found";
}
foreach($matches as $match){
    list($fullstring,$path,$filename,$id)=$match;
    echo "<div>fullstring=$fullstring</div>";
    echo "<div>path=$path</div>";
    echo "<div>filename=$filename</div>";
    echo "<div>id=$id</div><br>";

    // ...now do any necessary substring processing.
}
```

output:

```
fullstring=https://www.example.com/gallery/image3.jpg
path=https://www.example.com/gallery/
filename=image3.jpg
id=3

fullstring=example.com/gallery/image9.jpg
path=example.com/gallery/
filename=image9.jpg
id=9

fullstring=http://example.com/gallery/image14.JPG
path=http://example.com/gallery/
filename=image14.JPG
id=14
```

By isolating the parts of the string that you wish to keep, you can reduce the `str_replace()`/`preg_replace` workload.

Comment: @cobrax I have made a very general answer that may help you.  If you require further guidance please leave me a comment.  Let's move your question to some kind of useful resolution for future SO readers.